# iOS xib setting tableview cell constraint

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview

I am making a custom UITableViewCell.

There are two labels which are having dynamic height.

```
[label1 setNumberOfLine = 0];
[label1 sizeToFit];
[label2 setNumberOfLine = 0];
[label2 sizeToFit];
```

How can I add the constraint correctly?

I set the constraint like the following pic.
[image]

However, I got the following result.
[image]

The top label doesn't fit the content size.

Comment: Do you have a fixed cell height?

Comment: make label height accordigly label text and give cell height label height

Comment: Thabks abhi1992, the cell don't have fixed height, i want to set the cell height according to those two labels.

Comment: Thanks ishu hingu, the height i got from the textfield is the init height, i can't get the height that after textfield resized by the contents.

Answer (score 1):

I will suggest you to create outlets for NSLayoutConstraint in the h file for label1 height and label2 height(control+click and drag on the height constraint to the h file).

Now you can set the height for these constraint like.

```
self.label1HeightConstraint.constant=[self getLabelHeight:label1];
self.label2HeightConstraint.constant=[self getLabelHeight:label2];
```

Now you can return the height for the cell at index path as sum of these two heights.
The following function will return you the heights.

```
 -(CGFloat)getLabelHeight:(UILabel *)label
      {
               CGFloat maxLabelWidth =label.frame.size.width;
               CGSize neededSize = [label sizeThatFits:CGSizeMake(maxLabelWidth, CGFLOAT_MAX)];

            return neededSize.height;
        }
```

The number of lines should be zero for both cases.

Comment: Thanks al lot, but there is an other problem, I got the wrong height from the function

    -(CGFloat)getLabelHeight:(UILabel *)label
      {
               CGFloat maxLabelWidth =label.frame.size.width;
               CGSize neededSize = [label sizeThatFits:CGSizeMake(maxLabelWidth, CGFLOAT_MAX)];

            return neededSize.height;
        }

Comment: try setting the CGFloat  maxLabelWidth = self.view.frame.size.width-leftmargin-rightmargin;

Comment: You have to set the width of the label so get the required height using the above code.or you should give the width as mentioned in the previous line.